# onclick dialog should be positioned on top

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I am having jquery-ui dialog as in [here](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/creating-a-windows-like-interface-with-jquery-ui/)

I have customised it in such a way that when the dialog's minimized , it goes into a container  on the left and onclick a specific dialog in the container it restores , but i want it to restore on top of all dialog's and it must be show at the front.

Comment: Why can't you set high z-index to the dialog?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found another way of doing this without using Z-index

Just on adding the below line of code to the click function it works just fine.

```
dialog_element.moveToTop(true);
```

where diaolg_element will be the dialog which is clicked.

Cheers
Jeev

Answer (score 2):

You can set the zIndex to the dialog by

```
$( ".selector" ).dialog( "option", "zIndex", 20 );
```

Comment: u mean setting the z-index while the dialog is created ??

Comment: No.. when you restore the dialog, set the Zindex higher than others to bring it front.

Comment: I tried in this way. $('#dialog_window_minimized_container').click(function() {
window.minimized = false;
$( "'#' + div_id" ).dialog( "option", "zIndex", 20 );  }); is this right?? it doesnt seem to work.

Comment: Please give some high value and check. ie above 1000 or 10000 like this

Comment: It seems like your selector is wrong. Replace $( "'#' + div_id" ) with $('#' + div_id) and try

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22582/discussion-between-jeev1989-and-pitchai)

Comment: If it is still not working, assign a z-index value through DeveloperTools from the browser and check the dialog comes front. If not, a demo might be preferable